# Java split the input between double and string

Tags: java, split, fractions

I'm new and started coding about few of months.
I was making a program that calculating fractions but the problem is I want the user input form as like 1/2 2/3 3/4. So, how can I split those to put do = 1 and nu = 2 from user input?? or is it even possible?

Comment: Is this a command line program, a web application, mobile app, desktop GUI? We can give you better ideas if you show a very simple program and point to the part where you need help.

Comment: it's possible, and simple - you just collect the input as a String, and then split it by the symbol "/" to two substrings. Then just convert them to integers.

Comment: @erickson Yeah, it is very simple command line program. I'm using Eclipse tho.

Comment: @Assafs Thank you for help! I will try it then feedback to you guys! Plus, do I need import something before use split func?

Comment: For simple splitting on a delimiter, you can write `String[] parts = input.split("/");` I think using a "regular expression" to make sure the input matches the format you expect, and if so, to get the numbers you care about, is a better idea. It is a bit more complicated, but very, very useful to learn, and will give you better results.

Comment: Okay, so I split them '2/3' as string so I could get String [0] =2 [1] =3. But how could I convert them into integer? any hints?

Comment: `int numerator = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);`

Comment: Thank you so much guys, it really helped and learned a lot!